# Sip library for Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, sip

I have installed RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy on my raspberry pi.

I want to run a sip client on the pi, it should be able to register to a PBX (SIP Server), get a number, get calls and so on.

Is there any good sip library that is suitable to use in the raspberry pi?

thanks

Comment: Do you need client or you need to develop your own client?

Comment: I want to add some functionality to the client, so I guess I want to develop one (using some kind of source code/library for the basic sip functions like register, call, get call etc..)

Answer (score 0):

[liblinphone](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/overview) is a widely used open-source library for VoIP application development with API in C language. It also provides a python wrapper of SDK.